# A Chrome extension that displays a random picture from the chosen local folder for every new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to building Chrome extensions. I want it to be able to allow the user to choose a local folder and one random picture from there should be displayed for every new tab.

As of now, I have the images in the extension folder and have hardcoded the image names for access.

I read the following SO questions around this:

[Open (Import) file in a chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884140/open-import-file-in-a-chrome-extension?rq=1)

[Access Local Files using a Google Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912056/access-local-files-using-a-google-chrome-extension)

But I am not sure which one to implement and if they are the way to go.

Comment: The solution would probably be to open a file upload dialog (like a normal web page) and save it into a `Blob` to localStorage and then load it from there as a data url.

Comment: Is that for a single file? I want the extension to be able to access all pictures in a folder.

Comment: Do you need that access to be dynamic (files change) or not?

Comment: It should be dynamic. The user should be able to point to any folder that has images in it.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem

Comment: it's impossible to load local file. it is possible if you're using NPAPI. but NPAPI is being deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

It's **not possible**<sup>*</sup> with an extension to maintain a persistent access to a folder in a filesystem. Chrome Apps [can do it](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem), extensions cannot.

Your best bet is to allow upload of files into a [virtual filesystem](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/). But it will not allow modifying the pictures without interacting with your extension again.

Alternatively, you could integrate with some cloud provider, i.e. monitor a folder in Dropbox.

---

<sup>*</sup> P.S. Regarding NPAPI, yes, it's being deprecated, but there is an alternative: you can have a Native Host program that [your extension talks to](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). However, it makes it very awkward to distribute the extension - Native Host can't be submitted to Chrome Web Store. But in principle that can give you the full power of a native app.

Comment: Or have a Chrome app that sends the images to the extension.